# Ensure that a consumer group's offset is behind another group's

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two services, A and B, processing stuff from a Kafka topic. However, B must not process stuff from the topic before A is done doing so. Is there any way to ensure that B's `poll()` will only return records that have been committed by A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to create a pipeline and push messages committed by A to a new topic which B should subscribe.

Comment: In this case, is it A itself that must take care to push the messages to the new topic? Or is it possible to tell Kafka "whenever A commits messages, automatically push them to topic X"?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides you need to write a kafkaProducer.send command to push messages in the topic. I simple words you are creating a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the details of doing transactions in Kafka >=0.11 : https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/

But depending on what you're actually building, maybe having A produce back to another topic for B to consume (as @Abhimanyu suggests) may be the right option here.